# Tomcat Service stops on undeplyment

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tomcat

I have a web application which internally starts a server socket and listens to the incoming messages. When I am undeploying my web application it stops tomcat server also.

Can I know are there any settings that I need to update to handle this situation ?

My Environment : Currently I am using the default settings which comes from the installation. My tomcat version is "Apache Tomcat/7.0.10", JVM version is "1.6.0_24-b24", OS i am using is "Linux"

**Error in server logs shows** :

SEVERE: The web application [/sampleApp] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: Hmm, Tomcat is pretty explicit about the error. Stop your app threads when "undeploying".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why undeploying the application is causing Tomcat itself to stop, maybe looking some more at the logs and increasing the log level will shed some light. However your approach of creating a server socket within Tomcat is quite strange (I question why does it need to be in a webapp in the first place if its implementing its own socket protocol rather than HTTP).

The Servlet API explicitly recommends against creating new threads while handling HTTP servlet requests. Tomcat tracks its thread pools and resources associated with each webapp, and when you're creating a new Thread you're effectively going out of its model, which is what is creating that `SEVERE:` error. This is happening most probably when your `ServerSocket` gets a new client connection and you initialise a new `Thread` to handle it.

If you need to implement any multi-threading it should be in a [`ContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), which gets initialised when the webapp is loaded. The servlets then communicate to it if they need to offload any work to other threads. Never create new threads directly from a `Servlet`. You can also put the `ServerSocket` in the `ContextListener`, however you might want to rethink why you are handling your own protocol and HTTP (maybe using [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) makes more sense in your case?)